# Maven Assembly error : no entry name specified

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

In fact this is not a question because I've already found the solution but I've strugguled so long with it that I'd rather share this one with you than let it die in the depth of my mind

This problem occured to me on an existing project that was using maven assembly 2.2 for some time

The whole exception message was :

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2:assembly
>   (default-cli) on project
>   test: Failed to create
>   assembly: Error creating assembly
>   archive jar-with-dependencies: Problem
>   creating jar: no entry name specified

There was no more message even with a mvn -X

At the beginnig I thought it was due to a bad url like :

> jar:file://MY_FILE.jar!

But all this was caused by an hidden file named ".#log4j.xml..." which was automatically created by CVS during a conflict resolution

==> solution is resolve the conflict and remove the file

I've filed a bug report on this : [PLXCOMP-169](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-169)

Comment: You should leave your answer as an accepted answer and not change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said this is not a bug and will need an improvment from the plexus team.

Until then you will need to find by yourselves ".#" files in your project **AND** dependencies (this one was in a project of mine which was a dependency to the project beeing assembled).

Thanks to Jon to point me out the fact that an accepted answer would be more intuitive.